# 301 redirects from old URLS to new ones

Tags: mod-rewrite, redirect

I am redesigning a clients' old website to look better. They built a website themselves with very strange URLS. I have looked everywhere for the answer and I have achieved some success but not all by using 301 redirects.

They had urls like website/name ++.htm and I need to do a 301 redirect to website/name.php

Is there anyone that knows how I can 301 a URL that has a space ++.htm in the name.

Thanks

Comment: Try `RedirectMatch permanent (.*)\s\+\+\.htm $1\.php` and let us know if it works.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
RedirectMatch ^/([^+\s]+)\s*\+*\.htm$ /$1.php
```

This will redirect

```
http://example.com/name++.htm
```

to

```
http://example.com/name.php
```

In regex , **+** is a special character, it matchs the preceeding charecter 1 or more time, so to match it litterly in URI, you need to escape it by placing a backslash before it :

```
\+
```

Comment: Thanks very much for that. All I did was put RedirectMatch ^/([^+\s]+)\s*\+*\.htm$ /$1.php at the top of the page in my htaccess file and it links anything with + in the URL go to the page.